# How to join in three table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

I have three tables:

**group**

```
id_group (PK) | name
```

**registry_in_group**

```
id_group (PK-FK) | id_registry (PK-FK)
```

**registry**

```
id_registry (PK) | name | surname | dob (DATE)
```

I have to select group names they contain only registry with an age greater than 18.

This is my query:

```
SELECT g.name 
FROM group as g
JOIN registry_in_group as aig 
    ON g.id_group = aig.id_group
JOIN registry as a 
    ON aig.id_registry = a.id_registry 
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, a.dob, CURDATE()) >= 18
```

But this return also registry lower 18. Why?

Comment: Group is a reserved, which makes me think this isn't in fact your query

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that it finds the groups that have at least one registry older than 18, whereas you want to ensure that *all* registries in the group fulfill that condition.

You can use a correlated subquery with a `not exists` condition to filter on groups for which no registry is younger than 18:

```
select g.*
from groups g
where not exists (
    select 1
    from registry_in_group rig
    inner join registry r 
        on  r.id_registry = rig.id_registry 
        and timestampdiff(year, r.dob, curdate()) < 18
    where rig.id_group = g.id_group
)
```

Another option, built upon your query, is to use aggregation with a `having` clause to filter out the groups that contains a registry younger than 18:

```
select g.name 
from groups g
inner join registry_in_group rig 
    on g.id_group = rig.id_group
inner join registry r
    on rig.id_registry = r.id_registry 
group by g.id_group, g.name
having sum( timestampdiff(year, r.dob, curdate()) < 18 ) = 0
```

NB: as commented by Strawberry, `group` is a reserved word in all RDBMS; I used `groups` instead, to avoid confusion.